# SQL Pivot Table Question Column Values into Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, window-functions

I have a question regarding this query I cannot seem to figure out.

I'm trying to pivot the values below, here is some sample data.

```
Line  ID   Password
1       C1    Llama
1       C1    Elbow
1       C1    TV
2       C2    Password
```

Into something like this. The max columns I could make could be limited by 15 or 10.

```
Line    ID    Password1   Password2    Password3
1         C1      Llama      Elbow        TV
2         C2      Password   BLANK/NULL   BLANK/NULL
```

I've tried something like this below in a few iterations

```
SELECT ID, [1], [2], [3] FROM (
SELECT * exampletable) AS T
PIVOT (MAX(PASSWORD) FOR Line IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS PVT
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend window functions and conditional aggregation. THis makes more sense if you have a column that defines the ordering of the records - I assumed `ordering_id`.

```
select
    line,
    id,
    max(case when rn = 1 then password end) password1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then password end) password1,
    max(case when rn = 3 then password end) password3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by line, id order by ordering_id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by line, id
```

You can expand the `select` clause of the outer query as needed to handle more possible values per `(line, id)` tuple.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I knew there was an easier way but had no clue how to go about it. You saved me a bunch of time! Now I can enjoy my weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a dynamic number of passwords, then the code should go dynamic to match.

You were missing the enumeration for the PIVOT.

```
with t as(
select*from(values
(1,'Llama'),
(1,'Elbow'),
(1,'TV'),
(2,'Password'))a(ID,Password)
), RunningNums as(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by ID)RN from t
)
SELECT ID, [1], [2], [3]
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM RunningNums
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT(
    max(Password)
    FOR RN IN ([1], [2], [3])
)as P
```